# network simulator

Tags: java, windows, emulation, simulator

I need to build a device emulator which can communicate over real IP address

I need to create as many instances I can for the device. With one IP and MAC address for each emulator instance

Can can any one guide me how this can be achieved?

Comment: What language? What platform?

Comment: are you asking about virtual network interface?

Comment: Yeah, what platform? I'm working on an interface for NS-3 in Java.

Comment: Many tools can do this. Google "network capture replay". Why are you trying to do this, and at what protocol level?

Comment: well i need to create a test environment for multiple virtual devices 
that acquire ipaddress from dhcp

Comment: It's interesting that you've started a bounty on this question, but not included any further information on what is missing from the answers that have been given.  If you need more info, you need to define what kind of device you want to emulate.  If you want one computer to show up on your network with multiple MAC addresses, you're in for a looong haul.  You'll pretty much need raw data layer access for that, and if you've never done any hardcore network programming, it isn't the route you want to take.  Are there acceptable fallback situations that you can describe?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Five or six years ago, I was stuck writing a network emulation layer for a PS2 game.  I was told that all the classic behaviors of an internet connection had to be displayed; realistic loss characteristics, packet reordering, latency, rush-induced packet loss.  Essentially, I was told to implement the internet in a couple weeks.

I suggested just bouncing all our game traffic off a remote echo server.  When I was told that it was absolutely forbidden to send development traffic out over public wires, I simply created a server that everyone pointed their PS2 devkits at that would store every packet it received and send a doppleganger (full of an id for the original packet plus a bunch of random garbage to make it the same size) out to the echo servers I ran.  When the doppleganger was received, I would pass the original packet on to its original destination.

Boom.  Internet simulation with all the thorns in less than 8 hours.

UPDATE:

Given the success of the answer here, I reimplemented the game echo service a while back. It seemed that github might be a better place to stash it, so [here it is](http://github.com/foodini/game_echo_service): If it works for you, great! If not, let me know. I expect its current state to be shaky at best.

Comment: Sir, this is an epic solution.

Comment: That's an excellent solution to the problem! I'd have trouble convinving the powers that be that none of the development traffic was actually escaping.

Comment: I suppose the only downside is to make the test conditions repeatable in the future.

Comment: If you want to save yourself a great deal of work AND prevent leaking of development traffic, you can simply accept an inbound connection, encrypt it all, send it to the remote echo server, and decrypt it all when the echo is received.  MBAs tend to think that they understand that "encryption" means "problem solved."  Not having to locally store all the data is a lot harder than encrypting.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual PC 2007

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6&DisplayLang=en

.

Virtual Machine Network Driver

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=dc8332d6-565f-4a57-be8c-1d4718d3af65&displaylang=en

.

VMware Player: Windows

http://www.vmware.com/products/player/

Comment: setting up virtual machines for 1000s of devices will be too costly. also most of the devices doesn't event run Linux or Windows

Comment: You can add virtual ethernet adapters to this virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

[Add a Range of Virtual IPs in Windows](http://www.ozzu.com/mswindows-forum/how-can-add-range-virtual-ips-windows-one-shot-t53117.html)

See the February 21st, 2006, 1:18 pm post reply by **gil.elessar**

.

For your reference:

[Netsh commands for Interface IP](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh.mspx?mfr=true)

[Netsh commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738592%28WS.10%29.aspx)

You can use commands in the Netsh Interface IP context to configure the TCP/IP protocol (including addresses, default gateways, DNS servers, and WINS servers) and to display configuration and statistical information.

Comment: ok that can be possible solution but what about the mac-addresses. Is there is any what that i can have different mac-address for each of the ipaddresses?

Comment: mac-addresses (also called physical address) is a device address to which network packets are sent to. Above solution is creating Virtual IP's for same device.

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea woul be to used [User-Mode Linux (UML)](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/), a port of the Linux kernel in user space. It allows multiple virtual Linux systems (known as guests) to run as an application within a normal Linux system (known as the host).

It very light, in CPU and memory. For instance I'm using more than 10 UML in the same time on a "not-too-recent" PC, using [Netkit](http://wiki.netkit.org/index.php/Main_Page), a network simulator based on UML.  UML is light because it's a native application, not heavy virtualisation (vmware, virtualbox, qemu) neither para-virtualisation (xen).

As the network interfaces are implemented to be able to connect to other UML machines (using uml_switch), you can have any MAC address you want. If you need to connect these UML machines to your system or external hosts, you can create virtual devices using TUN/TAP.

PS: If you're on Windows, you can try [CoLinix](http://www.colinux.org/), port of Linux Kernel for M$ OS, I don't know if it has same characteristics than UML.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using loopback adapters. Using this you can set any IP or mac address. Works great for emulating various network connections.

Answer (score 0):

you need to study the datalink layer in depth in the part of coding --  then you can understand the how it get mac address and the communication b/w mac and ip

Comment: will this technique even on fake ip and macaddresses?(fake in sense that no physical NIC exeists. )

Answer (score 0):

depending on what kind of device you need, you may be happy with a number of virtual PC engines, the overhead is high (whole PC is emulated instead of just a network interface) so you won't end up with 1000 machines, but this is an "out of the box" solution - and each virtual PC can have a number of virtual network cards.

Comment: well the emulation the device is not the problem at all what the actual challenge that i am facing is that how will i acquire or set the ipaddress of a emulator such that that communicates over LAN just like real NIC or nay ip enabled device.

Comment: The host computer (on which the virtual machines work) has its standard network card set up as forwarding connections from virtual machines transparently. And as you set up the OS on a virtual machine, you set it up just like usually within that OS (can be even via DHCP) - it can be Linux, Windows, whatever. Then the multiple virtual machines, with multiple virtual network cards (each with own IP and MAC) communicate through the physical network card. And so you end up with one Windows PC running 10 Linuxes each with 8 network cards, for 80 virtual network cards on one physical one.

Comment: setting up virtual machines for 1000s of devices will be too costly. also most of the devices doesn't event run Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you better not start reinventing the wheel. There are hardware as well as software solutions for this particular problem. They are also very well suited to network load (and throughput)-tests.

The downside is such devises are quite expensive.

Comment: can u provide some examples of such softwares

Comment: http://nsl.csie.nctu.edu.tw/nctuns.html is a popular and sophisticated solution. It's complicated to set up though.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco pakcet tracer allows you to emulate network traffic with an gui. Im surpised no one mentioned that (its limited to cisco devices but the standard is same across devices so it  would be learning commands for your specific device).

Try doing a google search because under normal circumstances its only available to ccna students but I kept a copy because my teacher let me.

Or you might find someone posted a copy from their class somewhere on the internet.